# Gridview builder range error index flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gridview

GestureDetector`(` onTap: (){
getImages();
},
child: SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: 155,
child: selectedImagesnew.isEmpty
? const Center(child: Text('Add Images')
)

```
                           : GridView.builder(

                         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                         itemCount: 4,
                         gridDelegate:
                         const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                             crossAxisCount: 1

                         ),
                         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           // TO show selected file
                           return Container(
                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               border: Border.all(
                                 color: Colors.black26
                                 ,width: 2
                               )
                             ),
                             child: kIsWeb
                                     ? Image.network(
                                     selectedImagesnew[index].path)
                                     : Image.file(selectedImagesnew[index]),
                           );

                         },
                       ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

After adding a first image, as you can see item count is 4 .I am getting Range error index only valid value is 0:1 in the remaining three containers. And when I tap the second container photo is getting uploaded but it still shows error in the remaining containers. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Because your list **selectedImagesnew** not sure have 4 elements after you fetch data (maybe your getImages() function).

you need change:

```dart
itemCount: 4,
```

to:

```dart
itemCount: selectedImagesnew.length,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).